# ReactStars component displays border around stars

Tags: reactjs, frontend, web-component, web-frontend, rating

I want to use a `<ReactStars />` component in my application but when I click a star, that component displays a border around stars. How can I make it not to display that border when I click a star?

I tries to use id or className prop to define a none border style but it doesn't work, I have no other idea what to try. I looked into list of attributes of that component but I didn't find something to cancel that behaviour.
I made a minimal example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-bird-3hufy?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the outline property on the class named react-stars, which is applied by the library to the stars row.

Here is your updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-goldwasser-xn96c?file=/src/App.js).